# apex trigger help

Tags: apex, trigger

In the 'New local suplier' page, i need to create an Apex trigger (before insert, before update) to pre-insert data after local supplier selection

1. Local supplier creation start with a lookup field to select a local supplier from the EUDW_supplier_data object
2. As soon as the local supplier is selected, start an Apex trigger to pre-insert the data from the EUDW_supplier_data object, if available:
3. Fill out selected Supplier_Name from EuDW_supplier_data in Supplier Name field
4. Fill out Supplier_ID from EuDW_supplier_data in Supplier Number field
5. Fill out EU_Supplier_ID from EuDW_supplier_data in Parent Supplier field
6. Fill out Supplier_VAT_Number from EuDW_supplier_data in VAT Number field
7. Fill out Business_Unit_Code from EuDW_supplier_data in Business Unit field

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Too many underscores is making the question hard to read :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, i havent try nothing till now, i am very new in salesforce, ive worked before with oracle apex and plsql but this is smth different, do you understand what i need? or should i explain me better?

Comment: @theGreatDanton can you help please?

Comment: @user1498168: I think you should take Doug's advice.. Try to write a trigger, if you face any problem , paste the code here and people will be happy to help you out.. :)

Comment: I agree with the advice to try something first, and then come back with questions about the specific challenges you're facing -- but I also want to point out that a little formatting can go a long way in making your question easier to follow, and therefore easier to help you with.  Formatting is your friend!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you have a read of the quickstart coding guide http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm and have a look at the documentation freely available on http://developer.force.com/

Comment: well thanks, i already did.. can someone tell me if what i am trying to do can be done with a trigger? someone told me to try controllers...

Comment: If you want to populate those fields when the record is written to the database, use a trigger. If you are wanting to populate them on screen in response to user actions then use Visualforce with an Apex Controller.

Comment: Local ERP systems feed EuDW with supplier data. What we require is EuDW to feed SFDC with this data in the form of supplier tables. When a new local supplier is created in SFDC the system provides a drop down list of EuDW supplier base. This way we enforce data integrity between SFDC and EuDW and local ERP’s. So by selecting the supplier name with the lookup from the EuDW table i want to show in my fields (on page) any relevant information and then save this supplier as a local one in my table, i think in this case i shoul use triggers... who can give me a very short example to start from?

Comment: You can find a short example of what a trigger looks like in the Quick Start guide. Also there is a lot of documentation available online where you will see other examples.

Answer (score 0):

@user1498168 - While the documentation can provide a fuller, richer learning experience the basics of a trigger can be understood with the following code sample:

```
Trigger <triggerNameHere> On <objectNameHere> (Comma Separated list of Trigger Contexts here) {
// Those trigger contexts are: (before insert, after insert, before update, after update, before delete)
//Within a trigger you're given access to Trigger.new
// and, if it's an AFTER insert, or AFTER update trigger you're given access to 
// Trigger.old . These are call trigger context variables and you can utilize them
// as a pre-defined LIST of objects that cause the trigger to run. 
//
//Generally, you'll want to iterate over the trigger objects thusly:
for(objectNameHere iterationVariable : Trigger.new) {
  // do what you need to do with your object here.
}
//If you're in a BEFORE trigger, this is all you need to do. 
//If you're in an AFTER trigger, you'll need to do a DML call like this:
update trigger.new
}
```

Make sense?